# Trouble embedding PHP within CSS styled radio buttons to populate a form

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently writing a program that allows information in a database to be edited by populating a web form.

However, the web page is formatted with customized radio buttons and I seem to be having trouble embedding PHP inside the HTML tags. My understanding is that combinations of CSS and HTML don't allow PHP to written inside. Is that the problem here? (The document is saved as a PHP file)

```
 <div id="radio4">
     <div class="radio1" >  
         <input id="mgender" type="radio" name="GENDER" value="m" <?php echo ($GENDER == 'm') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>> 
             <label for="mgender"></label></div></div>

 <div id="radio5">       
     <div class="radio2">  
         <input id="fgender" type="radio" name="GENDER" value="f" <?php echo ($GENDER  == 'f') ? "checked" : "" ; ?>>
             <label for="fgender"></label></div></div>
```

If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: And where the `$GENDER` comes from?  Through `$_POST` or `$_GET`?

Comment: Do you get any syntax errors?

Comment: Close your input tags also, and use `checked="checked"`. The others seems to valid to me if `$GENDER` has set. And why labels are empty?

Comment: @lolka_bolka Completely valid markup for HTML5. No need for changes here.

Comment: css and html are rendered on the client side - in the browser - and php is used to generate html (mostly...) on the server side. So I don't see any reason why a combination of all would lead to problems.

Comment: I'm partial to the shorthand echo for inline stuff like that: `<?= 'Your Text' ?>`

Comment: Scratch that, the labels are the way they are because I don't entirely understand CSS right now. That just seemed to work.

Comment: I think it's that way because the inner code is enclosed in two div tags, I'm not really sure, I'd need to edit it around to remember why I wrote it that way.

Answer (score 0):

try with this regular expression :

```
<div id="radio4">
     <div class="radio1" >  
         <input id="mgender" type="radio" name="GENDER" value="m" <?php if($GENDER=='m'){echo"checked";}?> /> 
             <label for="mgender">Male</label></div></div>

 <div id="radio5">       
     <div class="radio2">  
         <input id="fgender" type="radio" name="GENDER" value="f" <?php if($GENDER=='f'){echo"checked";}?> />
             <label for="fgender">Female</label></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't been able to figure this out. I thought writing it the above way worked, but it was just automatically checking one of the radio buttons.

I think it may be a configuration issue associated with my Apache server, or something in the php.ini files. Anyone have any knowledge of this?

In my text editor the close tag at the end of the php statement stops being read as code.

So, for example in this statement:

```
 <input id="mgender" type="radio" name="GENDER" value="m" <?php echo ($GENDER == 'f') ? checked="checked" : "" ; ?> [nothing read after this point] />
```

*edited to add code.